# Can Apache Camel be used as a general Load balancer

Tags: apache-camel

I wanted to know if Apache Camel can be used as a load balancer for any HTTP web server.

I am thinking of Apache as I can add some customization to it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use camel for that. 
Something like this might do it for you (in a route builder):

```
from("jetty://http://0.0.0.0:8080/my/path")
    .loadBalance()
    .roundRobin()
    .to("http://server1:8080/my/path","http://server2:8080/my/path");
```

You can check out more load balancing options here: http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to load balance HTTP, then see this page as well, as you would need to configure the http endpoints to be bridged:
http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html

And as well the matchOnUriPrefix=true, to match any requests coming in.
And if you use jetty on all the endpoints it can scale up, using non-blocking continuations.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of course you can use camel as a Load balancer. I have so far used it very successfully. Have a look at this discussion [Load balancing using camel](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Load-balancing-camel-in-real-world-td5717381.html#a5717541). This will be useful to get started. Have fun riding on Camel!